# How to send money to contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle, ether, remix

In remix ide, we have UI designed in such a way that we can pass ether or Wei directly and execute the functions.  When we use truffle to deploy the contract, how can we pass ether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Creating a contract and sending ether in truffle (ganache)

In order to create and send some ether to a contract, you need to call the .send function on the contract.

### Example:

The following command will create a new instance of MyContract, then call it's `.send` function with the amount of ether to send and the address from which to send it:

```
MyContract.new().then(c => c.send(10, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}))
```

### Funded account addresses:

When ganache starts it will create 10 different addresses for you each of which contain 100 ether. You can access them via `web3.eth.accounts[`0..9`]` and can get their balances like:

```
web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]).div(10**18).toFixed(6)
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer. If not let me know so I can further assist.

Comment: So `c.send()` sends Ether, but if you want to have a function that takes wei then do  your suggested `.div(10**18)` (`.toFixed(6)`) within.  Is that what you mean to say?

Answer (score 0):

**To send ether to contract on deployment using ganache and truffle**

Truffle exposes two additional variables 'network' and 'accounts'.
Network lets you perform specificactions depending on the network/chain being deployed to (e.g do this if deployed to ropsten).
Accounts is a list of accounts provided to you by your Ethereum client and web3 provider.

Check the docs for more info: https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations/#available-accounts

```
const MetaCoin = artifacts.require("MetaCoin");
module.exports = async function(deployer,network, accounts) {
  await deployer.deploy(MetaCoin, { from: accounts[0], value: 
  "2000000000000000000" });
}
```